# Why isn't my pictureBox moving (Visual C ++)?

Tags: c++, controls, picturebox, trigonometry

I am in the early stages of making a basic two-body problem program (for those of you that don't know, a 'two-body problem' is when you have two bodies in space being gravitationally attracted to each other). I have it set up so that on each timer tick the objects (which are pictureBoxes) move in accordance with the direction (in degrees) inputted into a textbox.

Once a couple of IF statements make sure that the values in the textbox are valid, they do this inside of a Button_Press event (the button will start the simulation):

```
this->SimTick->Enabled=true;  //Master timer for simulation
radians1=(int::Parse(DirectionBox1->Text))*(3.14/180);  //Converts the degrees entered for the first object into radians for use in trig functions
radians2=(int::Parse(DirectionBox2->Text))*(3.14/180);  //Converts the degrees entered for the second object into radians for use in trig functions
```

Inside the timer_tick event:

```
this->Object1->Location.X+=(int::Parse(VelocityBox1->Text)*cos(radians1));
this->Object1->Location.Y+=(int::Parse(VelocityBox1->Text)*sin(radians1));
this->StartStop->Text=(radians1.ToString());  //This is just here to check that the math was correct, which it is
```

I haven't coded C++ in a while, so this might be a really simple mistake, but does anyone have any ideas, or need any more code pasted?

Comment: What data type is Location.X and Location.Y?  If they are ints, then you might just be hitting rounding issues.

Comment: @woolstar I would assume that they are ints. Why would rounding issues cause such a problem though? I normally input 1 for velocity, and 90 for a direction. The 90 becomes 1.57, which would truncate to 1, so it should still move, right?

Comment: cos() and sin() should never be larger than 1, so if velocity is only 1, then at 45 degrees you'd only get 0.7 and 0.7 which truncates down to zero.  Try a velocity of 10 and see if you get anything.

Comment: @woolstar Still nothing with a velocity of 10, or 1000 for that matter.

Comment: I would confirm that `int::Parse(VelocityBox1->Text)` is returning a valid number next.

Comment: Well, I got the pictureBox to move. It turns out that the Location.X/Location.Y properties don't do anything on their own, and you need to use the Location property to actually move the pictureBoxes.

Comment: You are right in stating that it would truncate to 0 though, so that will need to be fixed, and 90 degrees seems to be straight down, so I will need to fix that as well.

Comment: Er... forgot that a higher Y value is actually down in computers, and not up like in math. All that's left is to try and remove the truncations.

Answer (score 0):

Besides updating the Location property properly to get it to take new values, you probably want to keep a temporary x & y as a float so that you can add fractional values to it.

```
typedef struct { float x, y ; } floatcoord ;

floatcoord  tmpLocation ;
tmpLocation.x += int::Parse(VelocityBox1->Text)*cos(radians1) ;
tmpLocation.y += int::Parse(VelocityBox1->Text)*sin(radians1) ;

this->Object1->Location.set( (int) floorf( tmpLocation.x), (int) floorf( tmpLocation.y) ;  // or however you update Location
```